# No escribe (guarda) el XML que toma desde el servidor

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Tengo una app que anteriormente leia un archivo xml desde un servidor y lo guardaba en el telefono para que el usuario pudiera ver el contenido sin conexion a internet, he pasado mi aplicacion a kotlin y me encuentro con el error de que el archivo ya no lo guarda o no lo escribe en la memoria, anteriormente utilizaba esta funcion en un Asyntask pero donde esta el while me da error y no he podido solucionarlo, gracias.

```
val conexion: HttpsURLConnection
        val urlArchivo: URL
        val url1 = "Mi URL"
        val fileOut: FileOutputStream
        val buffersize = 1024
        val buffer: ByteArray

        try {
            urlArchivo = URL(url1)
            conexion = urlArchivo.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
            conexion.readTimeout = 1000
            conexion.connectTimeout = 1000
            conexion.doInput = true
            conexion.requestMethod = "GET"
            conexion.connect()

            ruta = conexion.inputStream
            fileOut = FileOutputStream(archivo) // ubicacion archivo

            var bytesEscribir: Int
            buffer = ByteArray(buffersize)

            while ((bytesEscribir = ruta.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                fileOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesEscribir)
            }
            Toast.makeText(activity!!.applicationContext, getString(R.string.sinc_exitosa), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            ruta.close()
            fileOut.close()
            conexion.disconnect()
```

Comment: Podrias detallar el error?